# Is there any guitar modelling software for PC?

Tags: guitar, virtual-instrument

Note: I am not looking for amp modelling. I know there are many. I am also not looking for midi based PCM synth.

What I am looking for is a signal processing software (just like the amp simulators) with the very same functionality like Line six modelling guitars or Roland's G-5 or GC-1

Comment: what specifically? Acoustic simulation is a comb filter (or a chain of EQs) along with some soft reverb and delay. There are tons of sitar VSTs, and I simulate a reasonable humbucker on a single coil by chaining 2 gain pedal sims with some EQ.

Comment: Many thanks for the question. I thought about not a special effect, more like a specialized thing which allows to select a specific guitar from a list of say 1-2 dozen guitars. (just like an amp simulator allows you to select a specific amp) and just like as  Line 6 modelling guitars on board electronics allows it.. I am interested mainly in jazz guitars and secondly in acoustic models. (Tele and Strato and Les Paul versions with different pups are not my topic) For example for Line 6 Variax the jazz boxes are. 1954 Gibson® ES®-175 and 1953 Gibson® Super 400, 1961 Gibson® ES®-335

Comment: Take a look at Strum GS-2 by Applied Acoustics. It doesn't put brand names on its guitars, but between the edit page and presets, it should give you plenty of tones.

Comment: Strum is not a signal processor I mean its input not an actual guitar signal, instead midi or similar alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Making virtual instruments real and believable is a matter of having faithful sound banks but... while this is enough for "keys" (pianos, organs, synths, etc.), it's only a starting point for guitars if you are playing them through a keyboard.
Due to that, being that I carry out some arrangements and transcription of pop and jazz music for the band I am part of - as an enthusiast, not as a professional! -  and that I can play keyboards only, I have found over the years that the best results are achieved through software packages that provide you with the knowledge of how a guitar has to be played (especially for grooves), while you only need to put in place the right chords and select the grooves within a library. In this perspective, I recommend a couple of products by a famous German company: Strummed Acoustic and Scarbee Funk Guitarist. They are sample-based. I suppose there are dozens of equivalent products out there, but I had the chance to try only these two and they were really effective for me.
I don't know what kind of music you play but I hope to have provided you with some ideas.
Ciao

Simone

Comment: I agree with sampling. Martin makes a DI sampler box too. You plug in and choose what (Martin) guitar to be today. A local performer uses one with his Martin guitar.

Answer (score 1):

There are various pieces of software that let you do this. Your best bet is to look at specific VSTs for your favourite DAW, but you can also find this functionality in various applications badged as amp/effect simulators.